# How to debug webview on Amazon Fire Phone?

Tags: webview

Does anyone know how to debug [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) on Amazon Fire Phone? When I goto chrome://inspect, I see below and it does not allow me to debug any webview:
[image]

I have set `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` equal to `true` and have further verified that i am able to inspect and debug the same `apk` on a nexus device. Also further, I have [amazon web app tester](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/webapps/debug-webapp.html?preferredLanguage=en_US) installed but turns out that app is useful only for debugging web apps running under the Silk browser that comes installed with amazon devices.

On a separate note I have following questions:
1. Does anyone know if Amazon WebView works on Fire Phone? The [official statement](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/android-fireos/docs/awv-faq) says its only available on 3rd and 4th generation Fire tablets.
2. If it does work, is it debuggable? [This](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/android-fireos/docs/building-and-testing-your-hybrid-app) page says: Because of the way that the Amazon WebView binaries are deployed, you must have a Kindle Fire HDX or Kindle Fire HD tablet to test the Amazon WebView functionality

Comment: answer to 1. Does anyone know if Amazon WebView works on Fire Phone? is yes. i tried it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for improved methods, but a current working way is to use [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Home.html). Weinre will run a server on your computer, and includes javascript in your head that is able to communicate with that server. Then it provides a web inspector *similar, but not as good as* Chrome DevTools.

1. Install weinre on computer. (I used npm)
2. In Terminal, run `weinre --boundHost YOUR_IP`
3. Add a script tag to your head `<script src="http://YOUR_IP:8080/target/target-script-min.js"></script>`
4. Load onto Kindle Fire Phone
5. On computer, go to the url `YOUR_IP:8080/client`
6. Choose target device and inspect.